# Write to body slowly on guzzle

Tags: php, guzzle, guzzle6

I'm trying to send data on body, using put request with Guzzle.
How can I write data to body, similar to this read command of get message?

```
while (!$body->eof()) 
{
    $data = $body_origin->read(1024*1024);
}
```

Something i tried:

```
$dest_stream = Psr7\Utils::streamFor();
$response_dest = $client_destination->request('PUT', $url_dest, 
[
    'stream' => true,
    'body' => $dest_stream,
    'read_timeout' => 100,
    'Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream',
    'headers' => 
    [
        'Content-Length' => '0'
    ]
]);

while (!$data_to_send->eof()) 
{
    $data = $data_to_send->read(1024*1024);
    $dest_stream->write($data);
}
```

Comment: The [body](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#body) parameter can be a [StreamInterface](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/5.3/streams.html) which you can presumably do whatever you want with

Comment: Hi, i tried several ways using streams, but it seems the data is not sent upstream. It just fills the buffer. I'll edit and post a sample I tried.